# How to union/group array of objects by same values and by some property?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have some array:

```js
[
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "5bb1a457"
  },
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "6bb3G465"
  },
  {
    destination: "8801856472841"
    message_id: "5bb1a457"
  }
]

//after union, i need to get result:
 
[
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "5bb1a457"
    destination: "8801856472841"
  },
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "6bb3G465"
  }
]
```

Help please, myabe is it possable to group or to union by property with unique value. just to join all objects which have same values by specified peoperty and missing properties add into joined objects

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you have  syntax error in your array: `Line 28, Column 5`

Comment: `_.groupBy(arr, 'billable')` doesnt help you?

Comment: @gfullam, i didn't try, i layed out code only

Comment: @TheReason, doesn't, first array is after _.groupBy(vm.listMsgs.data, 'message_id')

Comment: @axon actually it works [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bee2vjrv/), btw you just need to pass another property name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can map it by the key you want to check and eventually merge it:

```js
var d = [
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "5bb1a457"
  },
  {
    billable: 1,
    source: "Facebook",
    providerAccountId: 5,
    message_id: "6bb3G465"
  },
  {
    destination: "8801856472841",
    message_id: "5bb1a457"
  }
];

var res =  d.reduce((ac,x) => {
   if (ac[x.message_id])
     Object.assign(ac[x.message_id],x); //if you want to preserve original use a new object as target
   else
     ac[x.message_id]=x;
   return ac;
 },{})

// and then you can map it back to array
var res2 = Object.keys(res).map(x => res[x]) 

console.log(res)
console.log(res2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the array and filter it while applying the properies of an already inserted object.

This proposal uses an (really) empty object as hashtable for the reference to the object who are filtered. If an object with the same `message_id` exist, then all properties of the actual object are assigned to the object with the hash.

```js
var array = [{ billable: 1, source: "Facebook", providerAccountId: 5, message_id: "5bb1a457" }, { billable: 1, source: "Facebook", providerAccountId: 5, message_id: "6bb3G465" }, { destination: "8801856472841", message_id: "5bb1a457" }];

array = array.filter(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.message_id]) {
        this[a.message_id] = a;
        return true;
    }
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        this[k] = a[k];
    }, this[a.message_id]);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(array);
```